# K8s object to hold only text data

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

For each namespace in K8s (existing ones), I would like to create an object which contains a text, for example the Jenkins URL of the job.

Which K8s object should be used for this?

Thanks,

Comment: Configmaps are what you are looking for to store arbitrary data.

Comment: ... or you could keep it in the namespace annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jordanm said, you can use config maps as volumes, you can add them as values by following the below method

Create ConfigMap From Literal Values, using the --from-literal option.

To do so, follow the basic syntax:

```
kubectl create configmap [configmap_name] --from-literal [key1]=[value1]
```

To see details from a Kubernetes ConfigMap and the values for keys, use the command:

```
kubectl get configmaps [configmap_name] -o yaml
```

The output should display information in the yaml format:

```
…
apiVersion: v1
data: 
  key1: value1
…
```

Once you have created a ConfigMap, you can mount the configuration to the pod by using volumes.
Add a volume section to the to the yaml file of your pod:

```
volumes:
  - name: config
  configMap
    name: [configmap_name]
    items:
    - key: [key/file_name]
    path: [inside_the_pod]
```

For more info refer to this [document](https://jamesdefabia.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_create_configmap/).